# Groovy - print directories in the path

Tags: groovy

Given the following path of a file:

```
/home/fixed/foler/myScript.grooy
```

how can I obtain individual directories in the path to myScript.grooy?

Ultimately I want /home, /home/fixed, /home/fixed/folder to be printed in a log file in new lines.

Output of Log File:

```
/home
/home/fixed
/home/fixed/folder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with recursion:

```
String fileName = '/home/fixed/folder/myScript.groovy'

def printFilePath(String fileName) {
    File file = new File( fileName )

    if( file.path != '/' ) { printFilePath file.parentFile.absolutePath }
    else { return }

    if( !file.isFile() ) println file.absolutePath
}

printFilePath fileName
```